# samba-ad-dc.service: Skipped due to 'exec-condition'

Tags: samba

OS: Debian 12 (bookworm)

When I try to start samba, `systemctl start samba` runs with no output, but `systemctl status samba` outputs:

```
* samba-ad-dc.service - Samba AD Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exec-condition) since Wed 2023-08-30 19:35:52 CEST; 10s ago
  Condition: start condition failed at Wed 2023-08-30 19:35:52 CEST; 10s ago
       Docs: man:samba(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
    Process: 1414 ExecCondition=/usr/share/samba/is-configured samba (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 26ms

Aug 30 19:35:52 debian-srv systemd[1]: Starting samba-ad-dc.service - Samba AD Daemon...
Aug 30 19:35:52 debian-srv systemd[1]: samba-ad-dc.service: Skipped due to 'exec-condition'.
Aug 30 19:35:52 debian-srv systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in samba-ad-dc.service - Samba AD Daemon being skipped.
```

testparm doesn't return any errors in the smb.conf file.

log.smbd:

```
[2023/08/30 19:31:50.587835,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:1741(main)
  smbd version 4.17.10-Debian started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2022
```

log.nmbd:

```
[2023/08/30 19:31:49.882020,  0] ../../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:901(main)
  nmbd version 4.17.10-Debian started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2022
[2023/08/30 19:32:12.939108,  0] ../../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:398(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****
  
  Samba name server DEBIAN-SRV is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 192.168.0.110
  
  *****
```

I tried reinstalling the system, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you eve get around this? I'm stuck exactly as you were :(

Answer (score 2):

If you did not set up Samba to be an "active directory domain controller" (e.g. as described [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller)), then I think this is expected behaviour.

The confusing thing is that the systemd samba service is actually an alias for the samba-ad-dc service:

```
root@server:/# ls -l /lib/systemd/system/ | grep samba
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  464 Oct 10 17:17 samba-ad-dc.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19 Oct 10 17:17 samba.service -> samba-ad-dc.service
```

In the systemd status output you can observe that the service file has an execution condition that invokes `/usr/share/samba/is-configured samba`. If you take a look at this script you will find that it reads your samba config using `testparm` to find if the server role parameter equals "active directory domain controller". If not, it exits with a return code of 1 (failure), hence the failure to start the samba-ad-dc service.

The actual systemd service controlling the Samba server is `smbd.service`.